# EF Core many-to-many updates other end of relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I have a simple model:

```
public class Property
{ 
     [Key]
     public Guid ID {get;set;}
     public string Title {get;set;}
     public ICollection<PropertyType> PropertyTypes {get;set;}
}

public class PropertyType
{ 
     [Key]
     public Guid ID {get;set;}
     public string Title {get;set;}
     public ICollection<Property> Property{get;set;}
}
```

We're updating a Property like this

```
    await context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    List<PropertyType> removeItems = entityToUpdate.PropertyTypes.Except(propertyInputModel.PropertyTypes).ToList();
    List<PropertyType> addItems = propertyInputModel.PropertyTypes.Except(entityToUpdate.PropertyTypes).ToList();
    foreach (PropertyType item in removeItems)
    {
        entityToUpdate.PropertyTypes.Remove(item);
    }
    foreach (PropertyType item in addItems)
    {
        entityToUpdate.PropertyTypes.Add(item);
    }
    await context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    return entityToUpdate;
```

The issue is that an added ProperType also get updated, how do I prevent that

Comment: Can you please post somewhere a full [mre]? Also can you please explain the `added ProperType also get updated` statement?

Comment: Sorry i can't your point, Can you explain your question in more details?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that an added PropertyType is being updated is likely because EF Core is tracking changes to the entire object graph that includes the PropertyType entity when it is added to the Property entity's PropertyTypes collection. This can cause EF Core to try to update the added PropertyType entity when the SaveChanges method is called.

To prevent this, you can detach the added PropertyType entities before calling SaveChanges. This will prevent EF Core from tracking changes to those entities and attempting to update them.

```cs
await context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
List<PropertyType> removeItems = entityToUpdate.PropertyTypes.Except(propertyInputModel.PropertyTypes).ToList();
List<PropertyType> addItems = propertyInputModel.PropertyTypes.Except(entityToUpdate.PropertyTypes).ToList();

foreach (PropertyType item in removeItems)
{
    entityToUpdate.PropertyTypes.Remove(item);
}

foreach (PropertyType item in addItems)
{
    // detach added entities to prevent updates
    context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Detached;

    entityToUpdate.PropertyTypes.Add(item);
}

await context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
return entityToUpdate;
```